# class="input-group" is taking up 100% width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tablecolumn

When the user clicks on a cell in the thead, I populate it with an input element and a filter icon.  The problem is it's making the width of the column jump:

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lag9x/):

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='clickhere'>Click here
            </th>
            <th class='clickhere'>or here</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>

    $(document).on('blur','.clickhere input',filterBlurred);
    function filterBlurred() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('th').html('&nbsp;');
        }
    }
    $(document).on('click','.clickhere',filter);
    function filter() {
        $(this).html('<div class="input-group"><input class="form-control"><span class="btn input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-filter"> </span></div>');
        $(this).find('input').focus();
    }
```

Comment: I can get the width of the column by saying: $(this).closest('table').find('thead th:eq(4)').width()

Comment: And I can set the max-width: as well. hmmm...

Comment: Because you have two columns, you could add th {width: 50%;}  http://jsfiddle.net/Lag9x/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var Variables = {};
    Variables.theadID = 0;

    // For every thead
    $('thead').not('.no-filter').each(function(index, thead) {
        var local = {};

        if ($(thead).attr('id')) {
            local.id = $(thead).attr('id');
        } else {
            // We'll assign a unique id
            Variables.theadID += 1;
            local.id = 'fw0Thead' + Variables.theadID;
            $(thead).attr('id',local.id);
        }
        // Set the max-width for each column via css.
        local.str = '';
        $('th',this).each(function(index, element) { // for every th inside of this thead
            if (!$(this).hasClass('no-filter')) {
                local.str += '#' + local.id;
                local.str += ' tr.fw0Filter th:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ') {';
                local.str += '  max-width:' + $(this).width() + 'px;';
                local.str += '}';
            }
        });
        local.css = document.createElement("style");
        local.css.type = "text/css";
        local.css.innerHTML = local.str;
        document.body.appendChild(local.css);
});
})();
```